# Filtering between two values in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to filter items that are between two values that are inputed as text. For example if I have this values:

```
people=[
{
   name: 'Ricky',
   age: 21
},
{
   name: 'Mike',
   age: 32
},
{
  name: 'Arianna',
  age: 23
}
];
```

And in the template I have something like this:

```
{{input type='number'}}min Age
{{input type='number'}}max Age
```

How would I only display the people who are between the age of 20 and 25? Having the values 20 and 25 acquired via the input.
jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kosoyo/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Are your inputs bound to anything? To get values out of them you’ll need something like `{{input value=lowerBound type='number'}}`

Comment: I tried adding value to the input helper and it's not working.

Comment: I suggest that you make a JS Bin to represent your problem. You’ve only given isolated bits of your code, not enough for anyone to actually suggest anything useful.

Comment: jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kosoyo/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with a link to a working JS Bin and some explanation.

Comment: Nice, but how would I make the table display all the items if no filter is added? Also I would like it to work along-side the checkbox filters.

Comment: I’ve answered the question you created this post for. If you have other questions, you should open another question.

Comment: By the way the only thing was changing the condition from `lowerBound !== undefined && upperBound !== undefined` to `lowerBound && upperBound`. I don't understand why you needed another question for this, but whatever thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn’t give much context, but assuming that those values are stored in `people`:

```
people.filter(function(person) {
  return person.age >= 20 && person.age <= 25;
});
```

Given your update, still lacking context:

```
var lowerBound = parseInt(this.get('lowerBound'));
var upperBound = parseInt(this.get('upperBound'));

people.filter(function(person) {
  return person.age >= lowerBound && person.age <= upperBound;
});
```

[Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/turewileya/2/edit) is a working version of your JS Bin. You were trying to use `lowerBound` and `upperBound` without `get`ing their values from the form. You were also trying to use `filterBy` improperly: `filterBy` only works for simple equality, you need `filter` for a more complex comparison.

Comment: How would it be if the values where acquired via 2 different text input in the template?

Comment: I added info to what I am referring to, does it help? I want the user to type the min and max age and filter them out. How can I get the input and added to the lowerBound and upperBound variables?